# Define array to obtain data from range as "double" var type

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to VBA, so please bear with me.
I want to tell VBA to get an array from a range of cells. The user will paste a column of data into cell C2 so cells below C2 will be populated. The number of cells populated is up to the user.

I am also going to need each of the elements in the array to be taken as doubles as I'm going to make operations with them.

Therefore if the list is

```
1.2222
2.4444
3.5555
```

Then I need the array to preserve the decimal points.
How do I do this?
This is what I've got this fur, with no luck:

```
Set ThisWS = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1")
Dim InputValues() As Double 'Define Array
Dim LRow As Long             'Define length of array
With Sheets("Hoja1")
    LRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
InputValues = ThisWS.Range("C2:C" & LRow).Value 'Error 13: data type doesn't match
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: You would need the array `As Variant`, thats the only type supported for loading into an array.  As its only a single column you can easily loop the cells and add to an array of doubles manually

Comment: OT: Please remember to give feedback -this is becuase I just saw [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124058/vba-error-9-when-using-for-each-on-an-array)- on each of your questions, mark answers and stuff, else, another user with the potential same issue won't know what helped.

Answer (score 1):

`Excel.ActiveWorkbook.` isn't needed in Excel, it is implied.  I didn't need to type cast the cell value `CDbl(.Cells(x, "C"))`.

[image]

```
Sub Example()
    Dim InputValues() As Double
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long

    With Worksheets("Hoja1")
        lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        ReDim InputValues(lastRow - 2)

        For x = 2 To .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            InputValues(x - 2) = CDbl(.Cells(x, "C"))
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

---

This example is more efficient but won't make a noticeable difference unless you are working with a very large amount of data.

```
Sub Example2()
    Dim InputValues() As Double, vInputValues As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    With Worksheets("Hoja1")
        vInputValues = .Range("C2", .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value2

        ReDim InputValues(UBound(vInputValues) - 1)

        For x = 1 To UBound(vInputValues)
            InputValues(x - 1) = CDbl(vInputValues(x, 1))
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I like example 2 more. If you wouldn't have posted that, I would have :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks.  I figured the first example' pattern would be more familiar to most readers.

Comment: I left that `Excel` because from OP narrative couldn't be excluded that excel was being called from a client application.  Too bad it seems we're not likely to get feedback from Lauratoyos whatsoever....

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I agree with you about Thomas 2nd solution, may be because it's quite the same as mine!

Comment: @user3598756 not quite the same as yours.  One of the OP's requirements were "I am also going to need each of the elements in the array to be taken as doubles".  But again, that's just me being picky.

Comment: OP's requirement furtherly specified _"I need the array to preserve the decimal points"_ so that a `Variant` array approach would do. And anway  I dealt with any possible strictly `Double` part of the question reminding the user of the `CDbl()` function. This to say that I think the _core_ of both our answers is the use of a `Variant` array

Comment: Hi, I've applied example 2 but i;m getting an array InputValues that is filled with zeros -- where am I going wrong?

Comment: Empty cells will show up as zeros.  Do you need to skip empty cells?

Comment: Yeah, it's just that the code seems to be working, but it is not returning any results for some reason

Comment: `MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Sum(InputValues)` Insert this line after the `Next` to test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set ThisWS = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1")
Dim CurRow As Long
Dim LRow As Long             'Define length of array
    LRow = ThisWS.Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim InputValues(1 to LRow - 1) As Double 'Define Array

For CurRow = 2 to LRow
    InputValues(CurRow - 1) = ThisWS.Range("C" & CurRow).Value
Next CurRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply go like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim InputValues As Variant 'Define Array

    With Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1") ' refer to wanted worksheet
        InputValues = .Range("C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).value 'fill array with values in column "C" cells from row 2 down to last non emtpy one
    End With
End Sub
```

should you ever need to handle array values as of `Double` type, then you can use `CDbl()` function

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you can assign `.Value` and `.Value2` arrays only to a `Variant`

As a side note if the range is formated as table, you can just do something like

```
Dim InputValues() ' As Variant by default
InputValues = [transpose(Hoja1!Table1[Column3])] ' Variant(1 to number of rows in Table1)
```